# How to play sound file when GCMIntentService onMessage fires?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, google-cloud-messaging

In my application I am using GCM services. I want to beep or play a small mp3 file at onMessage function.

My GCMIntentService is extended from GCMBaseIntentService.

Can somebody please share the code or suggest me how to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, title, when);
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; // To play default notification sound
notification.sound = Uri.parse("PATH_TO_YOUR_SOUND_FILE"); // to play custom notification sound
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)   getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nm.notify(System.currentTimeMillis(), notification);
```